# StackOverflow Google Login on Safari not work

Tags: ios, iphone, google-api, safari

I have an old iPhone 6 with iOS 12.5.5 and I'm trying to login on StackOverflow with my account Google. But when I tap on `Login with Google` nothing appens. Nothing is shown. I'm already logged in Google on Safari.

What is the problem?

Comment: Questions about Stack Overflow itself belong on [meta]

Answer (score 1):

There was a [tweets](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/1502788125285879817?t=l8Omw2P3CRk_NDLiJZBRow&s=08) that stack is having some access issues and during the day there were a couple of maintances being done.